# Why would JmDNS service discovery work on a Motorola Droid running Android 2.1-update1 and not on an HTC Incredible running the same Android version?

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1, jmdns, motorola-droid

I have successfully gotten JmDNS working on Android 2.1 testing on a Motorola Droid by using MulticastLock, but recently got an HTC Incredible as second test device, and JmDNS discovery doesn't work at all.  I should mention that broadcasting a service still works and everything appears to run normally, but serviceAdded() never gets called.  Does anyone have thoughts on why this might be?  I was thinking it might be a permission issue, but I don't get any exceptions...

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a huge multicast bug in the current platforms. Take a look at the issue tracking: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15
JmDNS did not work for me on neither Milestone (2.0.1, 2.1update1) nor Nexus One (2.1update1) since I was never able to discover any broadcasted service.
Strangely, they closed the issue on Nov, 18th. I don't know what's currently going on but am desperatly hoping for FroYo, 2.2